# Minimum number of cubes of integers that sum upto a natural number n

Tags: number-theory

We define $f(x) =$ minimum number of positive perfect cubes that sum up to $x$.
 For example,$$f(17) = 3(17 = 1^3 + 2^3 + 2^3)$$
$$f(9) = 2 (9 = 1^3 + 2^3)$$
How can we find $f(x)$ for any number $x$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the _Waring Problem_? An exact solution isn't known for all $x$, but good upper bounds are known.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Not a duplicate.  That was about  $\max_x f(x)$.  Here we want to compute $f(x)$ for any given $x$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oh, sorry, this was a mistake. Still, [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem) is relevant. For example, $f(23)=9$.

Comment: You might look at [OEIS sequence A002376](https://oeis.org/A002376) and links there.

Comment: $G(3)=9$ so the $ 1 \leq f(x) \leq 9$.

Comment: The answer is $9$ ... this is the Waring problem ...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit sure, but OP asks what is the minimal way to express $x$ as sum of cubes while Waring asks for the maximal, so OP function $f(x)$ is bounded between $1$ and $9$ and a trial and error method to find the minimal have a **Exp** run time, he asks for method, i think i saw a method for finding sums of squares but not for cubes, may be some one could generalize the method to give fast results.

Comment: a **Linear** time algorithm could find $f(x)$ but it needs at least $x$ number of array cells, which is very consuming for RAM memory, check  out https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-the-minimum-number-of-cubes-that-sums-a-given-integer-n